# Cannot use import statement outside a module of axios

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, functional-testing, web-component-tester

while react component testing I'am facing this issue and I don't understand how can i solve this issue. I have added all the necessary elements but still facing this issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dswaO.png)

I'am trying to check react component testing but still facing an unexpected issue...

Answer (score 0):

The error points that you are using a import statement outside a module , because import statements are only supported in modules in js. So this can be solved by 2 ways.

1. In your package.json file , add type=module as below :

> {
>
> ```
>  // ...
>
>  "type": "module",
>
>  // ...
>
> }
> ```

2. Replace all your import statements with require.

Comment: i have already mentioned this... but stil its not working

Comment: Noticed you are using typescript , in tsconfig.json use 
"module": "commonjs" instead of   "type": "module"